# IBM MQ setup MCA UserId

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I need to set MCA User ID for IBM MQ Connection Factory in Java 8 (MQConnectionFactory com.ibm.mq.allclient:9.3.2.0).

On MQ Server I have a parameter ADOPTCTX(NO) and authentication works by java username on client side (-Duser.name) and after by username/password. I cant setup user.name in java because another system will not work.

I can't change ADOPTCTX to YES because MQ Server is third party provider.

I tried setup param in MQEnviroment.userID, but it doesnt work.

Now I have this code:

```
        com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.compat.base.internal.MQEnvironment.userID = mcauserid;
        com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment.userID = mcauserid;
        PropertyStore.user_name = mcauserid;
        ....
        MQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new MQConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, username);
        connectionFactory.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, password);
        connectionFactory.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true);
        ...
```

This works if java param user.name setted up to mcauserid.
Exist another way for define MCA UserID for connection factory?

Comment: When you say "I need to set MCA User ID ... ", do you mean you need to influence what is set in the runtime queue manager side MCAUSER - i.e. the user ID that is used for authentication and authorisation checks?

Comment: Sorry, yes I need to set MCA User ID on my (client side) in my application

Comment: Why not set this: `connectionFactory.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP,false);`  this will cause the client to send the USERID and PASSWORD in the MQMD instead of the MQCSP.  If you leave it set to true those values are sent in the MQCSP and the MQMD user is set to the user.name.  in the queue manager side it will see no MQCSP and use the MQMD values for USERID and PASSWORD for authIentication.   One limitation is the MQMD fields USERID and PASSWORD are limited to 12 characters each.I

Comment: Another limitation is that if you are not using TLS on your channels the password will transmit in the clear.   If you use MQCSP it will have at least some encryption (3DES). Always better to have a TLS1.2 or higher non-NULL cipher on your channel.

Comment: With connectionFactory.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP,false); I got  error  "IBM MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2012' ('MQRC_ENVIRONMENT_ERROR')"

Comment: I world suggest trying a few different versions such as the latest 9 3.0.x (LTS) release or 9.2.0.x.  both are still in support.   If you find one that works then likely you have uncovered a defect in the 9.3 CD and should open a case with IBM.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the MCAUSER attribute of the channel from the client-side.

The simplest solution is to have the MQAdmin set the UserId in the MCAUSER attribute of the channel.

Every application should have their own SVRCONN channel, so setting it should not be a problem and your application will still be able to perform authentication with the UserId and Password.